# getting dynamically created NPOCO object keys and values C# using reflection

Tags: c#, generic-list, npoco

I have to write an adminsitrative module where the sys admin can check all the values in a table that he chooses. Since the database has more than 100 tables, I wrote a generic method that returns an `IEnumerable<object>` with the data:

```
 public IEnumerable<Object> getAllData(string tableName)
 {
    IEnumerable<Object> result = new List<Object>();
    string sql = string.Concat("SELECT * FROM ", tableName);
    using (var uow = _provider.GetUnitOfWork())
    {
        result = uow.Instance.Fetch<Object>(sql);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Each item in the result is of type `object{NPoco.PocoExpando}`, and I need to get the keys and values for each item to convert them in a single string. When I make a foreach in the collection, this is what every item has on it:

[image: Visual Studio Watch Panel]

So, how can I get access to those "Keys" and "Values" properties? Getting the dictionary may help too.

Edit: 
This is the code that works, thanks to @Shaun Luttin for the answer

```
foreach (object item in result) 
{ 
    foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)item) 
    { 
        //Do awesome stuff! 
    }
}
```

Comment: The PocoExpando is very similar to an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking [at the source of NPoco.PocoExpando](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/blob/master/src/NPoco/PocoExpando.cs), it implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can cast each item and iterate the properties.

This is the same strategy that we would use to iterate the properties of an `ExpandoObject`. Here is a [DotNetFiddle that shows](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpEXUe) the strategy.

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic resultItem = new ExpandoObject();
        resultItem.Name = "John Smith";
        resultItem.Age = 33;

        // cast as IDictionary
        foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)resultItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the answer! the final code looks like this:

 foreach (object item in result)
            {
                foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)item)
                {
                    //Do awesome stuff!
                }
            }

Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @rhernandez Your final code isn't showing up in the comment.

Comment: I edited the question with the code, once again, thanks for the quick answer